# how to show, set the value for input filed in django form using forms in html <input value={{ value}} disabled> how to do it in django forms

Tags: python, django

i'm taking values from database table in views file and has to render those values to a form in template file which is created by using the forms class and i have to show those values for some fields and make them immutable.

```
   class OrderForm(forms.Form):
        pid=forms.IntegerField()
        pname=forms.CharField()
        pprice=forms.FloatField()
        person_name=forms.CharField(max_length=40)
        emailid=forms.EmailField()
        address=forms.CharField(max_length=40)
        city=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        state=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        zip=forms.IntegerField()
        card=forms.IntegerField()
        exp= forms.DateField()
        cvv=forms.IntegerField()
    def order(request,pk):
        pid=pk
        user_name=request.user.username
        qs=Product.objects.get(pid=pid)
        pname=qs.pname.format()
        list={'username':user_name,'pid':pid,'pname':pname}
        form=OrderForm
        return render(request,'order.html',{'data':list,'form':form})
```

i expect input filed with value that i passed by default which is immutable and when i submit i have to get same value i passed

Comment: i would like to obtain only month and year for DateField in form for exp can you help me in that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you're better off using a ModelForm.  It would be something like:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm)
   class Meta:
       model = Order
       widgets = {
           `immutable_field` : forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':True})
       }

def order(request,pk):
        pid=pk
        user_name=request.user.username
        qs=Product.objects.get(pid=pid)
        pname=qs.pname.format()
        list={'username':user_name,'pid':pid,'pname':pname}
        form=OrderForm()
        form.fields['immutable_field'] = "Some Value"
        return render(request,'order.html',{'data':list,'form':form})
```

If you already have an order then you can prepopulate the fields with `form=OrderForm(instance=order)`

Answer (score 0):

**Make field as disable from `Form` init method and pass `initial` value from view section**

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
        pid=forms.IntegerField()
        pname=forms.CharField()
        pprice=forms.FloatField()
        person_name=forms.CharField(max_length=40)
        emailid=forms.EmailField()
        address=forms.CharField(max_length=40)
        city=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        state=forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        zip=forms.IntegerField()
        card=forms.IntegerField()
        exp= forms.DateField()
        cvv=forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].disabled = True
        self.fields['pid'].disabled = True
        self.fields['pname'].disabled = True
```

**Here in view you can pass dictionary to form as `initial` value of fields.**

```
def order(request,pk):
        pid=pk
        user_name=request.user.username
        qs=Product.objects.get(pid=pid)
        pname=qs.pname.format()
        initial={'username':user_name,'pid':pid,'pname':pname}
        form=OrderForm(initial=initial)
        return render(request,'order.html',{'data':initla,'form':form})
```